# Add EditText widget while app is running

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-spinner

I'm trying to add EditText widget while app is running, and I'm not sure how do it. I hope it is possible.
What I want to do is that the user will select one item from a spinner list and then an edit text will appear.
For example, the spinner contains properties of human look and the user could decide if he want to add "hair shape" or "eyes color" EditText field or what ever there is in the spinner.

I did the code below but when I tried it nothing happens when I selected items from the spinner.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {

    switch(arg1.getId())
    {

    case R.id.parametersChoose: 

    LinearLayout test = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
    EditText field = new EditText(this);

    LayoutParams b = new LayoutParams(50, 30);
    field.setLayoutParams(b);
    field.setText("enter" + parametersChoose.getSelectedItem().toString());

    switch(parametersChoose.getSelectedItemPosition())
    {
    case 1:
        field.setId(1);

    }

    test.addView(field);

    }            
}
```

---

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


         <Button
            android:id="@+id/addWorkOut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="save" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Set new Exercise type" />

         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/newExercise"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:ems="10" >

         </EditText>

         <Spinner
             android:id="@+id/workOutChoose"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

         <Spinner
             android:id="@+id/parametersChoose"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/test"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >



                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10" >
                    </EditText>


                </LinearLayout>

             </ScrollView>



       ></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does your `ScrollView` have any other direct children? They should have only one. Also, is `test.addView(field)` getting reached?

Comment: i edited post, see XML code

Comment: Did you mean to add it to your `LinearLayout` inside your `ScrollView`? I think that's what you want

Comment: Yes, thats what i want.

Comment: By the XML code ScrollView have only one child, or im wrong?
How can i know if test.addView(field) is getting reached?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in there and step through to see if it reaches that point

Comment: Im not really familiar with Eclipse...

Comment: Then you should find a tutorial or look up debug questions using eclipse on here. Taking the time to learn how to use it will help tremendously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was my problem.
When using 2 or more spinners and trying to call them by `switch` the parameter `View arg1` does not points to the spinner him self but to is rows.
In order to call the spinner himself its needed to call the parent widget. Is value is from `AdapterView<?> arg0`.
The code need to look like this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {

        switch(arg0.getId())
        {
    ....
    ....
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you already have an edittext widget created before you run it, but make it invisible when you run it until you want it to be visable again. Just set the properties to visable when you want it to be seen!

Comment: I didnt know about that feature, ill try it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 ScrollView test = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
```

to

```
 LinearLayout test = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
```

According to the [ScrollView Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects.

You are giving your `ScrollView` multiple direct children with the `LinearLayout` you have in xml and now the `EditText` you created programmatically. Add the new `EditText` to your `LinearLayout` inside of your `ScrollView`

Comment: After i put the post i saw that error. but even after i fixed it its does not work.
When i select item from the spinner nothing happanes.